# Drools: difference between contains and memberof

Tags: drools

I'm reading [Drools 6.4.0 documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.4.0.Final/drools-docs/html/ch08.html).  I'm not sure to have understood the difference between `contains` and `memberof` operators: both work with collections and it seems that the only difference is that `contains` expect the contained object on the right side while `memberof` expect it on the left side, so they would be equivalent but I'm afraid I'm missing something.

Comment: Historic reason, from the times when a field had to be the lhs operand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This exemple is taken from Laune's answer to :
[Drools: Match local string from array in LHS of rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30989374/drools-match-local-string-from-array-in-lhs-of-rule/30993658#30993658)

```
rule "ruleY"
when
    Data( $los: listOfStrings )
    MyObject( string memberOf $los ) 
then
    //do stuff
end
rule "ruleY"
when
    MyObject( $s: string ) 
    Data( listOfStrings contains $s )
then
    //do stuff
end
```

They are complementary. Use the one or the other depending of the data you are having and the most logical way to express things.