# LHS Make Empty List Trigger Rule

Tags: drools

I am new to Drools so please bear over with the terminology!

Can I make rule trigger even though an empty list is involved in the LHS?

I have the code below.

There are two rules. One rule that insert facts and another rule that work on facts.

Part of fact B is to hold a list of facts A.

If this list is not empty then I am able to work on fact B.

If this list is empty then I am not able to work on fact B.

How can I write the code so I am able to work on fact B even though the list is empty.

If I activate the line below "b.As.add(a);" then I can work on fact B.

If I deactivate the line below "b.As.add(a);" then I can work not on fact B.

```
declare A
    nameA : String
end
declare B
    nameB : String
    As : java.util.ArrayList
end

rule "insertfacts"
when
then
    A a = new A();
    a.setNameA("A");
    B b = new B();
    b.setNameB("B");
    b.As = new java.util.ArrayList();
    b.As.add(a);   // Only with this line rule checkfacts fires
    insert( b );
end

rule "checkfacts"
when
    $b : B();
    $a : A() from $b.As;
then
    // take action based on object $b
end
```

Thanks

Thomas S

Answer (score 1):

To check if an object is present in working memory, you should use `not()` or `exists()` (depending on what you're trying to do.)

So your insert-facts rule should be like this:

```
rule "insertfacts"
when
  not(B())
then
    A a = new A();
    a.setNameA("A");
    B b = new B();
    b.setNameB("B");
    b.As = new java.util.ArrayList();
    b.As.add(a);   // Only with this line rule checkfacts fires
    insert( b );
end
```

This way you won't end up with extra `B` instances because insertfacts will only trigger when B doesn't exist (so, once.)

---

To check for an empty list, you can do `size == 0` as a check:

```
rule "As list is empty"
when
  $b: B()
  ArrayList( size == 0 ) from $b.As
then
  // At this point you know that As is an empty list, 
  // so you can insert stuff if you want
end
```

Alternatively, if you want to check that a *specific* object is not in the list, you can use `not memberOf`.

```
rule "Some instance A is not in the As list"
when
  $a: A() // the A instance we're trying to check
  $b: B( $a not memberOf As )
then
  // at this point As is a list of any size which doesn't contain the $a instance
end
```

Similarly there's `memberOf` for checking that the specific object *is* in the list:

```
rule "Some instance A is in the As list"
when
  $a: A()
  $b: B( $a memberOf As )
then
  // As is a list of any size which DOES contain $a
end
```

Note that there are two complementary operators you could be using to check that something is or is not part of a list: `memberOf` and `contains`. They're roughly the same, just with the arguments in different orders. See [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37986320/drools-difference-between-contains-and-memberof) for more information about those two operators.

---

Of course, if you don't care at all about the contents of the `As` ArrayList, then just don't check anything against it in the "when" clause. If you're sure you'll never have a situation where it's undefined, you can even skip the null check.

```
rule "We don't care whether there's something in As"
when
  $b: B( $as: As )
then
  // at this point we have access to the variable $as which will be
  // the arraylist; it may be empty, it may have stuff in it
end
```

... but you could always do a null check if you want to be safe:

```
$b: B( $as: As != null)
```

---

It was mentioned in a comment that you plan to write regular code in the "then" clause and loop through the list. Usually you don't want to do that -- if you just want to do work against the members of the list or a subset of the list (eg items of the list which meet certain criteria), Drools will implement the iteration out of the box for you.

As a simple example, let's say that you want to find all of the A instances inside of the list which have the name "PURCHASE" and update the name to be "VERIFIED_PURCHASE".

```
rule "Update PURCHASE to VERIFIED_PURCHASE"
when
  B( $as: As != null )
  $a: A( name == "PURCHASE" ) from $as
then
  $a.name = "VERIFIED_PURCHASE"
end
```

(You could add an `update` call on the right hand side if it's important to reevaluate rule matches, but in this simple example it's not needed.)

What will happen here, and what's usually a little difficult for people new to Drools to wrap their heads around, is that Drools will internally iterate through the `As` array list and check each item to see if it matches the requested criteria (`name == "PURCHASE"`). For each item it finds that matches the criteria, it will trigger the right hand side.

So for this example, if As has 10 items and 3 are named "PURCHASE", this rule's consequences ("then" clause) will trigger 3 times, once per matched item.

If you need a collection of these matches on the right hand side, you can use `collect` or `accumulate` depending on how complex your use case is.

```
rule "Get all purchases"
when
  B( $as: As != null )
  $purchases: ArrayList() from collect( A( name == "PURCHASE" ) from $as )
then
  // do something with $purchases here
end
```

Of course, you shouldn't then turn around and iterate through `$purchases` on the right hand side -- use the built-in way I showed previously.

The Drools engine is extremely good at optimizing performance; anything you put in the "when" clause gets optimized by Drools, which is why you want to do the iteration there (and let Drools leverage its own internal capabilities at that.)

The right hand side ("then" clause) is not optimized, so by putting the iteration and other logic on that side is going to make your rules perform worse in comparison. You may not notice the difference in a toy example like the ones we're working on in this question, but once you start processing hundreds or thousands of requests per minute, it will definitely start showing.

(I spent 10 years of my career supporting an embarrassingly huge collection of rules (scale is *millions* of rules) and I've never had the need to actually write a for-loop or any sort of iteration in the "then" clause. And the few places where I did find them as added by other engineers, I was able to remove them for non-negligible performance improvements. Let the framework do what it's good at.)

Comment: Thanks a lot. With the methods you show will I be able to reach the RHS of the "checkfacts" rule whether or not list $a is empty? I plan to write conventional code in the RHS of the "checkfacts" rule that loops through the list $a. And in my case it is perfectly OK that the list is empty.

Comment: Every variable declared in the "when" clause (eg. whenever I did `$x: `) is available for you to use in the "then". However your plan is not a good one: don't write loops in rules. You _can_, but you're just going to write more inefficient rules. I'll update the answer with more information.

Comment: Thanks a lot Roddy. Your tips and tricks were very hepful.